# Visa type for Military assessment UK

Tags: visas, uk, military

I just wanted to find out the visa I need to apply for when going for a military assessment in the UK and what supporting documents my sponsor back in the UK is to provide to aid my visa process.

Comment: Search this site for "British Army assessment" and you will find a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need to apply:

> From 11 July 2013 the Ministry of Defence requires all Commonwealth nationals seeking to enlist in HM Forces to demonstrate that they have lived in the UK with valid leave for a minimum of 5 years immediately prior to commencing the recruitment process.
>
> The only exceptions to this requirement will be those individuals who hold evidence from the Ministry of Defence dated prior to 11 July 2013 of either:
>
> - a written valid job offer,
> - confirmation of a training place,
> - a confirmed date to attend an assessment centre, or
> - a confirmed date to attend a psychometric test (RAF and Navy only).
>
> Applications from those seeking entry to the UK solely on the basis
>      that they are either seeking to commence or progress through the
>      recruitment process will fall to be refused unless the residency
>      requirement is met. For example, students who have previously held
>      lawful leave and studied in the UK for over five years but have
>      recently returned home for a short holiday may qualify if they have
>      obtained one of the documents outlined in the above paragraph whilst
>      in the UK.

([Source](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/armed-forces-arf/armed-forces-arf--2))

Comment: This doesn't address either the visa type required or the documents required from a sponsor. The only relevant section here says that the OP must have a confirmed date for assessment, which presumably he does or he wouldn't be applying for a visa.

Comment: @ReddHerring pretty sure the British armed forces don't give out assessment appointments 6 years in advance.... Any assessment appointment issued after July *2013* doesn't get you a visa.  So yes, the answer does address this nicely - you need significantly more than a visa.

Comment: This document appears to be outdated: "The MOD previously had a five-year residency in the UK requirement, in order to allow Commonwealth personnel to qualify for recruitment into the Armed Forces. Today’s announcement removes this requirement." https://www.gov.uk/government/news/armed-forces-to-step-up-commonwealth-recruitment

Comment: @moo Oops - I misread the text, but my point still stands because we have had questions recently about visa requirements for British Army assessments. The comment by Richard would seem to explain why